# Python script to compare the columns in two files

Tags: python, csv

First objective of this script is to take the first 14 digits from column 1 in two files(`1.csv` and `2.csv`). `1.csv` has the correct record mapping, where as `2.csv` has few records which don't match, so compare the first 14 digits of column1 from both the files and get the records which are not unique, this is accomplished with the script.

The second objective, which is not accomplished is for instance I have a record in `1.csv`, the same record with first and second column is there in `2.csv` and another record which first column same and second column which is different, I want this row to be also printed in the output.

Script is:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('1.csv', 'r') as csv1, open('2.csv', 'r') as csv2:
    csv1_lines = csv1.readlines()
    csv2_lines = csv2.readlines()

csv1_headers = [line[:14] for line in csv1_lines]
csv2_headers = [line[:14] for line in csv2_lines]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in csv2_lines:
        if line[:14] not in csv1_headers:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Your script basically works, you only compare the first 14 digits of each line and "2222222222222222" are common between the two files... If you want to have your expected output you'll need to compare more chars from each line.

Comment: thanks jerome.. i need help in doing that.. appreciate if you could help me in the code

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you *might* actually want something like this:

```
import csv
import io

file_1 = io.StringIO('''
1111111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
3333333333333333:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
'''.strip())

file_2 = io.StringIO('''
1111111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1111111111111110:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1111111111111123:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11111111111111:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2622222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyret
2222222222222222:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
4444444444444444:ppppppppppppppp
'''.strip())

good_reader = csv.reader(file_1, delimiter=':')
match_reader = csv.reader(file_2, delimiter=':')

good_values = [row for row in good_reader]

for row in match_reader:
    if row not in good_values:
        print(row)
```

However, it doesn't provide the same output that you suggest you're expecting. So perhaps you really want this?

```
good_values = [(row[0][:14], row[1]) for row in good_reader]

for row in match_reader:                                                               
    if (row[0][:14], row[1]) not in good_values:                              
        print(':'.join(row))
```

Comment: And what happened instead? See [mcve] if you're unsure how to explain what you tried, what you expected, and what happened instead. Because if I replace `good_values = ...` on in my first code block with the second code block it gives me the values that you're expecting to see. I've made some slight changes to make it output things in the format you showed.

Comment: And this example produces the output that you expect. But you say it doesn't without explaining what the difference is. This is not a write-all-your-code-for-you service. If you're incapable of making minor edits to code examples you should not be programming.

Comment: @kto - As a caution, insulting someone who is spending effort to help you is not a great way to get people to want to aid you in the future.

Comment: Dude he started insulting me first why dont you look at his comments